# Open a LOCAL client path on a new tab/window- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a rails application used internally in our organization.

All of the clients machines drives are mapped to a shared folders, all accessed by the same path, which looks like:
    `file://emc01a/projects/.../HTML_Report/index.html`

now, I am tried using the following block for this:

```
<%= link_to "Click here to view the report", @test_meta.test_log, target: "blank" %>
```

This generates the correct link, but the application doesn't respond to it at all.

Next, I tried:

```
<%= link_to "Click here to view the report", "http://"+@test_meta.test_log, target: "blank" %>
```

This made a difference and now a new tab is opened but the path isn't working as it is translated to: `emc01a/projects/.../HTML_Report/index.html`, which cannot be resolved by the browser to the actual path.

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to "Click here to view the report", "http://file:"+@test_meta.test_log, target: "blank" %>
```

This brought me to `file//emc01a/projects/.../HTML_Report/index.html`

So close, but I didn't make it work yet.

Any ideas please? :)

Comment: The value of `target` should be "_blank" not "blank"

Comment: This `@file-path` will be interpreted as `<the value of @file> minus <the value of path>` - is that what you're trying to do?  If it's meant to be a single variable then rename it to `@file_path` (minus signs are not valid characters for variable/method names)

Comment: Both options creates a new tab as requested, but it doesn't work well with the desired file path.

Comment: Ok, if 'blank' works in your browser then you're lucky, but '_blank' is the "official" correct value so you should use that.

Comment: Max, the actual name I'm using is @test_meta.test_log. edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Jeez i hate it when people do that.  Why not use your actual code in your question?

Comment: Sorry about that. As to the target field- I updated to "_blank" as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think the above issues (in my comments) are distractions and the real problem is a security issue:  by default your browser is sandboxed and cannot read files off a local filesystem (which the file:// links point to).

I think the way to handle this is to put a symbolic link to the shared folder in your rails app's public folder, then you can *serve* files from the shared folder from your app, as if they were any other asset.

eg in terminal, in your rails root folder

```
ln -s /path/to/the/shared/folder public/shared
```

eg if the shared folder is at "/emc01a/projects" you can make the symbolic link to the folder like so:

```
ln -s /emc01a/projects public/shared
```

Now you can link to this file `file://emc01a/projects/HTML_Report/index.html`

by subsituting `/shared` for `/emc01a/projects`:

```
<%= link_to "Click here to view the report", "/shared/HTML_Report/index.html", target: "_blank" %>
```

EDIT:  once you've got this working, you can do it more efficiently by setting up the config for nginx/apache/whichever-http-server-you-use to serve the files directly rather than via rails.  If it's just for an intranet site this might not be necessary.

Comment: Just realised i had the arguments to `ln -s` the wrong way round, sorry!  Editing.

Comment: Thanks. The security aspect could explain this behavior very much. But, as far as I see it, this solution only generates a valid url, which, apearantly, I was able to generate all along using the first command: `<%= link_to "Click here to view the report", @test_meta.test_log, target: "_blank" `

Comment: My point was that a url starting with "file://" is the problem.  If your url is `http://example.com/shared/foo.txt` then it is effectively being served from your application's public folder, which is where all assets live.

Comment: Hi, got it! thanks
Where would you recommend place the symbolic link when in production server? (should I define this in the `/app_name/current/` folder?) 
thanks

Comment: In the public folder like I said, ie `<appname>/public`

Comment: Hi, just tried it out.
When I hover on the link I see now:
`http://csi-eng-perf/shared/..rest_of_path../HTML_Report/index.html`
also, when clicked I'm being directed to this exact path, which cannot be found.
It worth mentioning that I'm using Capistrano for deployment, so I made the symlink definitions at `/app_name/current/`, when `current` by itself is a symbolic link to the latest release.

when I run `ls -l /public` I get:


    `lrwxrwxrwx 1 deploy deploy   18 Aug 31 01:18 shared -> /emc01a/projects/`

Comment: Some things to check.  1) Is the file actually accessable from your production server's `<railsapp>/public` folder? Ie can you `ls` to it on your production server, starting from `<railsapp>/public`?  2) Assuming you can do 1), then the url to access it in your app will be the `yoursite.com/<the path to the file STARTING FROM your app's public folder>`.  Its not clear from the info you've supplied what this should be.

Comment: 1) On my production server, when I'm in `<rails_app>/`, running both `ls /emc01a/projects/` and `ls /public/shared/` provides the same result.
2) I need the desired path to be `yoursite.com/shared/rest/of/path.html`.
but even when I'm pasting this link directly to my browser I get 404 page from the app ("The page you were looking for doesn't exist."). meaning some of the back routing to the actual mount isn't working from some reason. 
how can I debug this?

Comment: If you ssh onto your server, and type `ls <RAILS ROOT>/public/shared/rest/of/path.html` can you see the file?

Comment: My mistake. I tried it again today and worked flawlessly. Thanks!!